# uploading pdf file in Parse Table in android

Tags: android, parsing, pdf, parse-platform

I am trying to upload **pdf file** in a **Parse Table** and then fetch that pdf file.

I am new with **Parse.com sdk** and I have tried it with Image file using byte array but I don't have any idea about Pdf file ,to upload and then fetch.

Please guide me.Any tutorial will be very beneficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] data = yourpdf;
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("filename.pdf", data);

ParseObject test = new ParseObject("TestPdf");
test.put("name", "CV");
test.put("pdfFile", file);
test.saveInBackground();
```

Source : [Parse](https://www.parse.com/questions/android-upload-pdf-file-to-server)